# Can not understant ANY_OTHER

Tags: xtext

I am trying to learn xtext, and finding ANY_OTHER totally confusing, and have few questions aboit it.

I have only one production in my .xtext file.

```
document: text = '<' ANY_OTHER* '>';
```

when I run this as 'eclipse application', following inputs work correctly:

```
<>
< >
<.>
<....>
<.. ..>
```

but following appears fail:

```
<a>
```

with error **extraneous input 'a' expecting '>'**.

**Q1) Why ANY_OTHER is matching literal '.' character?**

I tried overriding ANY_OTHER as

```
terminal ANY_OTHER: .;
```

I believe this is as original definition in *Common Terminals* [here](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#_15).

Now the behaviour changes. Error for input  is gone. but if I try

```
<aa>
```

, gives error **extraneous input 'aa' expecting '>'**.

**Q2) Why overriding ANY_OTHER changes behaviour?**

**Q3) Why '.' is treated differently than 'a'? <..> is accepted, but  is not.**

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your three questions in a single answer, because this makes sense here.

By default the first line of a grammar looks like

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
```

unless you change it manually. I guess yours still looks like this. It means, that your own grammar will use the org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals by default, so you are right. The ANY_OTHER is specified in the "common" grammar.

According to the specified rules: The single . matches one character. Additional to this rule, you find an ID rule in the "common" grammar, which matches all textual characters and some others. Here is important, that the ID rule itself contains the quantity, while the ANY_OTHER rule only matches one single character. So by default the rules will match these examples

```
A   --> 1 instance of ID
*.* --> 3 instances of ANY_OTHER
AAA --> 1 instance of ID
A.A --> 2 instances of ID, 1 instance of ANY_OTHER
```

When overriding the ANY_OTHER rule, the parsing order changes. You can find some information about this in the documentation. This results in a different behavior:

```
A   --> 1 instance of ANY_OTHER
*.* --> 3 instances of ANY_OTHER
AAA --> 1 instance of ID
A.A --> 3 instances of ANY_OTHER
```

I hope this information helps.

Comment: thanks. some things are clearer. Let me see if I undestand it correct. For **Q1**, 'a' in `<a>` is matched as ID, and since I'm expecting *ANY_OTHER*, it gives error. is that right? Second part not clear yet, is by overriding am I altering precedence? Need to read docs again, I guess! Thanks again.